# @foreach loop in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC 3 and have this question to start with,

I have a class defined as

```
    Class abc 
    { public string Id { get; set; }
            public string str1 { get; set; }
            public string Action { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Title {get; set;}

    }
```

on my MVC2 aspx viewpage , I was using this class abc as model and had this code

```
 <%
   Model.ForEach(a => 
            { %>
               <%= Html.ActionLink(a.Title ,
                                   a.Action  ,   // <-- ActionMethod  
                                   a.Name  ,  // <-- Controller Name.      
                                   new { key = a.Id }, // <-- Route arguments.     
                                   new { title = a.str1 })%> 
                        <br /><br />        


                  <% }); %>
```

can you please help me convert this piece of code to MVC razor view ?,
     @model abc

```
 <%
            Model.ForEach(a => 
            { %>
               <%= Html.ActionLink(a.Title ,
                                   a.Action  ,   // <-- ActionMethod  
                                   a.Name  ,  // <-- Controller Name.      
                                   new { key = a.Id }, // <-- Route arguments.     
                                   new { title = a.str1 })%> 
                        <br /><br />        


                  <% }); %>
```

when I try to use @foreach ( var abc in Model) , I get error message , need to implement  Ienumerable ? How can I implement using @for  Please help or give me pointers.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you using a display template. This way you don't need to write any loops. So:

```
@model IEnumerable<abc>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

and then you define a display template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the model collection (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/abc.cshtml`):

```
@model abc
@Html.ActionLink(
    Model.Title,
    Model.Action,
    Model.Name,
    new { key = Model.Id },
    new { title = Model.str1 }
)
<br /><br />
```

Notice that templates work by convention. They must be placed in either the `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` folder or the `~/Views/SomeController/DisplayTemplates` folder depending on whether you want to reuse them between views from multiple controllers or a single controller. ASP.NET MVC first looks in the specific folder for a template and then in the Shared. The name of the file is also important. In this case your model consists of an `IEnumerable<abc>` where `abc` is the type of the elements in this collection therefore the display template must be called `abc.html`.

Same rules apply for editor templates. Just replace `display` by `editor`. Editor templates, as their name suggests, are suitable for putting input fields for editing a view model.

Answer (score 1):

The model shows only one object, not a list of objects.
Therefore you should not use ForEach but access the properties directly without a loop as Model.Name etc.
If you want a list of objects, then you need to update your controller to return a list of those by using a generic list, for example.

```
var abcCollection = new List<abc>();
```

That should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

user1005310,

a bit of understanding of the Razor syntax will help here. there are plenty of examples out there via Mr google. However, if you have a LOAD of code to convert, then you have a great little 'tool' out there to help (now OSS, originally developed by Telerik). Take a look at:

https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter

this is basically a convertor that takes an entire set of aspx views and converts them to Razor. I've tried it on a few test projects now and it works to 99% of my satisfaction, the other 1% is being addressed (or i can live with the minor tweaking).